# Identifying class instances created without any variable name

Tags: c#, xaml, object, user-controls

I was going to program a Windows Phone app in C# and XAML. I have created a usercontrol called BoxControl. That means I can create variables with that type.

I create instances of this control in a nested loop, seen below. The problem is that when I create instances of this control the way I have done it, how do I reference them in the code later? How do I uniquely identify each instance?

```
  // i = column, j = row
        for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {

                boxList.Add(new BoxControl());
                Grid.SetColumn(boxList[(i*3)+j], i);
                Grid.SetRow(boxList[(i*3)+j], j);

                BoxGrid.Children.Add(boxList[(i*3)+j]);
                boxList[(i * 3) + j].AddHandler(UIElement.TapEvent, new EventHandler<GestureEventArgs>(BoxControl_Tap), false);
            }
        }
```

For instance, if I tap one of them on the screen, I would like to do something with just that specific control. I have added handlers for that, but can't reference the object. Hope someone can help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about Windows Phone-App eventhandler, but WPF and Windows Form always give you the "sender" of the event. In your case, it is the particular BoxControl which was tapped, you just need to cast it.

Referencing it outside of the event is simply a matter of math, which you are already doing within the for-loop.

Comment: The eventhandler has a "sender", and I tried to cast it to a BoxControl type as you proposed. It worked nicely. Now I could change properties etc. on that specific control. Thanks!